# Plotting a set of data with two columns?

Tags: python, numpy, plot

I have a `.dat` file containing two columns of numbers. The x values are  in the first column and the y values are in the second.  I am having difficulties having python read in the first column only and then having it read in only the second column.  In the demonstration that my teacher did in class he used the last line of code:

```
from scipy import *
import numpy as np  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.loadtxt('repeatdata.dat')

# This is the line that I am referring to
plt.plot(data[:,0], data[:,1], 'ro')
```

I do not know what this line is doing but it looks like it might be doing something along the lines of what I am trying to do.

Comment: The last line is to plot the values. Can you print `data`? And what are you trying to do: read the values or plot the values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks right.

You need an additional call to `plt.show()` to actually show the plot.

You also need to make sure that the values in your `.dat` file are seperated by whitespace.

Also, are you sure that you are reading the right file? `np.loadtxt('repeatdata.txt')` loads a txt file.

**somedata.dat**

```
2 4
3 9
4 16
5 25
6 16
```

**main.py**

```
from scipy import *
import numpy as np  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.loadtxt('somedata.dat')

plt.plot(data[:,0], data[:,1], 'ro') 
plt.show()
```

Comment: Yes I am aware of the incorrect file I was just using that code as an example I will fix it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Some might also find it useful to shorten the notation using a star when plotting columns of numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.array([[1,4],
                 [2,5],
                 [3,6]])

plt.plot(*data.T, 'ro')
plt.show()
```

And similarly when plotting rows:

```
data = np.array([[1,2,3],
                 [4,5,6]])

plt.plot(*data, 'ro')
plt.show()
```